# Added graphics-drivers ppa, but no packages appear

Tags: apt, nvidia, ppa

I've tried to install the 396 drivers after doing...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

...assuming that it allow me to install `nvidia-graphics-drivers-396` or `vulkan`, but apt doesn't allow me to install either of those.

EDIT:
Sorry for not providing much detail at all.

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04, and kernel `4.16.15-041615-generic`.

I also have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M. This card is still technically supported by Nvidia.

Comment: You didn't provide much detail for us to help you?  eg. your Ubuntu version, or graphics card. If you open the PPA link you'll note "Dropped support for Fermi series (https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4656)" so it may mean your wanted driver was dropped.    https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.  Did you check your card wasn't declared EOL by nvidia for your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc I just updated it with more info. Sorry for not being specific enough in the first place.

Comment: @guiverc It doesn't look lik the GTX 860M is listed in the cards that were dropped. Also I don't think that the installer would b smart enough to prevent the installation of a package because a video board is X or Y and thus not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the package `nvidia-driver-396` can be installed to get the 396 drivers. However, it's much easier to go into **Software**; in the menu, under **Software and Updates** > **Additional Drivers**, you can install nvidia-driver-396.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run

```
apt-get update
```

at least once after the add of the PPA to your repository?

What I would do after that is a search to see what's available. Something like this:

```
apt-cache search nvidia | less
```

Then search for the packages as found on [the PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). If you can't find them, then the `install` command won't work.

Comment: I have already tried updating and doing an `apt search` for the 396 package beforehand. Thanks for trying to help, though.